Select top K arrays in an array of arrays, that will consist of the most unique elements
Given an array of arrays, with each sub-array contains unique elements, but among different sub-arrays, there might be the same element. Select the top K sub-arrays, that the union of all elements from the selected sub arrays is the maximum.

If there are multiple options, give one option (or all the options if not significantly more difficult).

What if the elements of a subarray can be millions?


e.g.
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  [2, 3, 4],
  [3, 4, 5], 
  [5, 6],
  [7]
]


If K = 1, then we select [1, 2, 3, 4], as we can get 4 distinct elements.
If K = 2, then we select [1, 2, 3, 4] & [5, 6], as we can get 6 distinct elements.
If K = 3, then we select [1, 2, 3, 4] & [5, 6] & [7], so we can get 7 distinct elements.
If K = 4, then we select [1, 2, 3, 4] & [5, 6] & [7] & either ([2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]), as the last one doesn't really matter, since they don't add any more distinct elements to the final results.

Other than brute force, or sort than brute force, are there any simpler options to tackle on this problem?

It sure looks like there's a pattern. What did you come up with?

I don't think there's a better than brute force solution since I'm not seeing how an efficient/greedy algorithm would be able to see far enough ahead to select the best set of subarrays. For example, if you had [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,4,5,6,7,8], [2, 3, 9]] with K = 2 it's clear that either of the first two subarrays should be selected for the K = 1 case. However, for the K = 2 case, if you had picked the first subarray, you would not be able to get the best possible result. Branching off each time there's a tie might work but you could construct examples that would make this approach slow.

This is a minor variation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem, that adds the requirements that all sets start with the same size. I strongly doubt that "same size sets" makes the problem any easier, and so it looks NP-hard to me. However the standard greedy algorithm is only off from optimal by a constant factor.
